# How to execute hive queries stored in a file and store the results in hive database using Spark application

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm reading a text file, where all hive queries are stored. I'd need to loop through all the queries and execute them on hive database and store the results in hive db
The code looks as below with the output. The RDD is read and invoke a method which executes the SQL queries on hive db and store them in the database

```
[abbi1680@gw01 ~]$ hdfs dfs -put  SQLQueries.csv /user/abbi1680/data/SQLQueries50.csv
```

--HDFS File

```
[abbi1680@gw01 ~]$ hdfs dfs -cat /user/abbi1680/data/SQLQueries50.csv
"abbi1680.PPPP","XXXX","select * from abbi1680.tbl1"
"abbi1680.QQQQ","YYYY","select * from abbi1680.tbl2"


scala> def HiveExec(TblName:String,dfName : String,HiveSQL: String) ={
     | val dfName = sqlContext.sql(HiveSQL)
     | dfName.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable(TblName)
     | }
HiveExec: (TblName: String, dfName: String, HiveSQL: String)Unit

scala> val ReadQuery = 
sc.textFile("/user/abbi1680/data/SQLQueries50.csv").map(line => 
line.split(",")).map(x=>HiveExec(x(0),x(1),x(2)))
ReadQuery: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Unit] = MapPartitionsRDD[3] at 
map at <console>:29

hive (default)> use abbi1680;
hive (abbi1680)> show tables;
```

I'm expecting the tables with names PPPP and QQQQ are created with the data as Tbl1 and Tbl2 resp.

It's not created any tables or threw any error.

Could someone please help.

Comment: Please paste the error you're getting.

Comment: What type of object is sqlContext? Is it a HiveContext or a SQLContext?

Comment: I've executed  this Spark shell, not quite sure which context it's. It works if we pass the variables as below, but when it reads from rdd, it doesn't work. val TblName="abbi1680.hottt"
    val dfName="dfTbl"
    val HiveSQL="select * from abbi1680.tbl1"
    HiveExec(TblName,dfName,HiveSQL);

Comment: You obviously had to define sqlContext somewhere.  Please include that line or share what type it is.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I've tried adding the context outside method and inside method. It didn't work. It didn't throw any error either.
Bear in mind, when we pass the variables to the method, it creates tables.
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)

The below works
    val TblName="abbi1680.hottt"
    val dfName="dfTbl"
    val HiveSQL="select * from abbi1680.tbl1"

    HiveExec(TblName,dfName,HiveSQL);

The issue is only when we use RDD, it doesn't work.

Comment: What happens if you do dfName.show() instead of dfName.write...?  Trying to isolate the issue as being a writing to Hive problem vs. something else.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for helping me out.

Since I don't have much time, I've chosen a different approach, which works

The below code works.

```
 cat SQLQueries50.csv
    abbi1680.RKKKK,AAAAA,select * from abbi1680.tbl1
    abbi1680.SPPPP,QQQQQ,select * from abbi1680.tbl2

val ReadQuery = sc.textFile("/user/abbi1680/data/SQLQueries50.csv");
val cnt = ReadQuery.count().toInt

for (line <- ReadQuery.take(cnt)) {
    val cols = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
    val TblName={cols(0)}
    val dfName={cols(1)}
   val HivSQL={cols(2)}
println(s"${TblName}|${dfName}|${HivSQL}")

HiveExec(TblName,dfName,HivSQL);

  }

def HiveExec(TblName:String,dfName : String,HiveSQL: String) ={
     val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
      val dfName = sqlContext.sql(HiveSQL)
      dfName.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable(TblName)
      }
```

Id want to avoid invoking for loop and complete the task using map function. It didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.